# Inint opencv matrix with NULLs

Tags: c++, pointers, opencv

How can I initialize `cv::Mat` of pointers with NULLs?

```
class CMyClass {..}

cv::Mat myMat = cv::Mat_<CMyClass*>(1000, 1000);
```

So I want to be able to check following:

```
if (myMat.at<CMyClass*>(10, 10))
     myMat.at<CMyClass*>(10, 10)->callMethod();
```

The `cv::Mat myMat = cv::Mat_<CMyClass*>(1000, 1000, NULL);` does not compile

Comment: you cannot have a cv::Mat of pointers in the 1st place

Comment: why do you think you need this ?

Comment: I want to assign an object of CMyClass to some pixels in image, but dont want to copy them to Mat, they are stored in some other data structure. And then I want to take neighbor objects in some image patch